# How to refresh the home frame in java awt indefinitely so it can accept requests?

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jframe, awt

I have the first frame with 3 actions to be performed

Home_Frame:
Choose option:

1. Perform action 1
2. Perform action 2
3. Perform action 3

Choosing each option results in more frames/tables being displayed.
The newly open frames I choose `HIDE_ON_CLOSE` as the action. For Home_Frame it is `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`.

My problem is described below:
When I choose say option 2 I can propagate through frames and close the newly open frames(except Home_Frame). 
Next I want to choose option 3 then I get the following exception

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at spark.cass.rw.SparkAPI_nodeGen.sm_loadArray(SparkAPI_nodeGen.java:138)
at spark.cass.rw.SparkAPI_nodeGen.sm_ExtractToArray(SparkAPI_nodeGen.java:98)
at spark.cass.rw.SparkAPI_nodeGen.getAll_NodeFaultsInfo(SparkAPI_nodeGen.java:43)
at gen.node.data.FilterNodeData.getNodes(FilterNodeData.java:85)
at gen.node.data.FilterNodeData.plotGM_pdf(FilterNodeData.java:110)
at gen.GUI.src.Plot_main.selectGMGUI(Plot_main.java:115)
at gen.GUI.src.GMFrame$ALsubmit.actionPerformed(GMFrame.java:107)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$1.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I do not know how to describe the problem in technical terms. Hopefully I have conveyed my thoughts properly.

Comment: *"The newly open frames.."* They probably should be modal dialogs. A modal component will block the code flow until dismissed. 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)

Comment: Thank you Andrew Thompson the links were useful and I have been able to resolve my problem.